# How to make a LAMP server publicly accessible?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, webserver, raspberry-pi, lamp

I bought a Raspberry Pi 2 in order to host a web server off my [ASUS RT-N66U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN66U/) router running the latest Merlin firmware.

I have the LAMP stack running, and also changed `AllowOverride` to `All` for `<Directory /var/www/html/>` in my Apache config, and have FTPed the site to that directory.

ipconfig = `192.168.x.x`

[CanYouSeeMe.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org) says IP = `24.245.x.x` but that it cannot see service at port 80

On the, router I have forwarded port 80/TCP to `192.168.x.x`

I own a `.com` which is directed to `192.168.x.x`

On any computer connected to my LAN, I can access the site from both the external address and my `.com` address. As soon as I disconnect from LAN (say disconnecting Wi-Fi), I can no longer access any of them.

I have confirmed with ISP (COX) they allow port 80 (after I forward port). I understand that dynamic IPs will provide issues down the road.

Disregarding that issue does anyone have any idea as to why my web server cannot be connected to from the outside world?

Answer (score 1):

> I own a `.com` which is directed to `192.168.x.x`.

The `192.168.x.x` network range is reserved internally for private LAN networks and not for publicly accessible WAN addresses. What you need to do is set the `.com` address to point to `24.245.x.x`.

That said, once you do that you need to also make sure your ASUS RT-N66U router can do [NAT loopback/hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) where it will be smart enough to understand that requests for the `.com` address that come from within your LAN should go to the `192.168.x.x` address instead of the `24.245.x.x` address.

But checking the documentation for the [ASUS RT-N66U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN66U/HelpDesk_Manual/) router, nothing in there appears to make any reference to NAT loopback/hairpinning. So if you want to test out the website internally on your LAN you might have to manually edit your hosts file to point the `.com` to that `192.168.x.x` address.

Regardless, there’s just no way the `192.168.x.x` address will ever be reachable directly for anyone in the outside world if you connect that to your `.com` domain. It has to be connected to the `24.245.x.x` address.

Comment: I updated my domain to forward to http://24.245.x.x/ and rechecked every setting in my router. The merlin firmware https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki does have NAT (actually two forms: ASUS, Merlin). I've disabled firewalls, enabled NAT, enabled port forwarding, forwarded port 80 and 100 to 192.168.x.x and still I'm getting connection errors.  I've even tried 24.245.x.x:80 and 24.245.x.x:100 but no luck.  Any ideas on what I should try next?    Thank you for the help by the way.